# jQuery Click Event Returns Init

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run the below jQuery code so it performs 50 clicks on an element on the page...

```
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   $(".next").delay(500).trigger("click");
}
```

but, it's returning

```
init [button.flat.pagination.next.excalibur, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: ".excalibur"]
```

How can I perform 50 clicks on this element?

Comment: What are you expecting it to return? I don't see anything that would be "returning" something.

Comment: I want it to actually perform a click on the page, 50 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is going to execute so fast all the "clicks" are going to end up happening at once. If you want to trigger a click every half a second, 50 times, do this

```
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(".excalibur").trigger("click");
    }, 500 * i);
}
```

Comment: @turnip derp.. fixed that.

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(".next").trigger("click");
    }, 500 * i);
}
680

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(".next").trigger("click");
    }, 500 * i);
}
1038

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(".next").trigger("click");
    }, 500 * i);
}
1092

Comment: Again, what are you talking about with returns? That code would trigger 50 clicks. 1 ever 500ms on any element with the class `excalibur`

Comment: I don't know why it doesnt trigger them. It's an ajax form and when I enter that code it gives me those outputs

Comment: What are you expecting to happen on the click event? Does it happen when you manually click? Are you sure the event is actually bound to the click event and not `mouseup` or something?

Comment: Normally every time I click it loads one page of elements through an ajax request. But it's a next button so I have to click 100 times if I want want the 100th page to be loaded, so I want to enter jQuery code to trigger clicks for me fastly...

Comment: And what exactly happens when you run that code from my answer? Does it load the next page? Does nothing happen?

Comment: See this is what happens: https://ibb.co/iL7ND0 -- https://ibb.co/hnkW6L

Comment: So when I click next button, ajax does a request and loads new list of items available for me to buy. If I sit and click 50 times, I can get to the 50th request I am interested in, so not to do that, I am trying to do a jQuery code so it does automatically click itself 50 times. All solutions I entered for this purpose does not show to be working...

Comment: What happens on the page itself. Your first screenshot is showing that the selector `.btn` is returning a whole bunch of elements which you'd be triggering clicks on all of. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: True, on the page itself nothing happens. My screenshots are from both answers on this page.

Comment: Well your problem isn't that it isn't triggering a click. It is either that the event you want isn't bound to the `click` event, or you aren't selecting the next button correctly, or you are triggering clicks too quickly.

Comment: Well this is the entire path: body > section > section > section > div.FUINavigationContent > section > div > section > div.FUINavigationContent > section > div.paginated-item-list.ut-pinned-list > div:nth-child(1) > button.flat.pagination.next

Comment: Maybe too fast? Sometimes when I click it takes good 2 seconds for ajax to load up the next batch.

Comment: So you are calling code that is selecting `.excalibur`? That isn't going to select the element you are trying to click on... Fix your selector and maybe it'll work..

Comment: it's .next, I corrected in the code still samething.

Comment: I'll select yours. Perhaps this is some security that company added I feel like that they dont want people to do this.

Answer (score 2):

> **How can I perform 50 clicks on this element?**

If you are just going to click your item for 50 times, you can do it without delay like the following:

```js
var counter=1;

$('.btn').click(()=>console.log(counter++));

for (let i=0;i<50;i++) $(".btn").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class='btn'></button>
```

**No console log version of above code**

```js
var counter=1;

$('.btn').click(()=>{
// you can place your on click stuff here
});

for (let i=0;i<50;i++) $(".btn").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='btn'></button>
```

Comment: 1
VM392:2 2
VM392:2 3
VM392:2 4
VM392:2 5
VM392:2 6
VM392:2 7
VM392:2 8
VM392:2 9
VM392:2 10
VM392:2 11
VM392:2 12
VM392:2 13
VM392:2 14
VM392:2 15
VM392:2 16

Comment: what do you mean by return? I just  used `console.log` in order to prove that the onclick button is firing!

Comment: console returned those numbers 1 2 3 4

Comment: that's because I placed a `console.log` in the `click` function to make sure that the code is working. you can replace that part of the code with your own code(or leave it empty).

Comment: See this is what happens: https://ibb.co/iL7ND0 -- https://ibb.co/hnkW6L

Comment: So when I click next button, ajax does a request and loads new list of items available for me to buy. If I sit and click 50 times, I can get to the 50th request I am interested in, so not to do that, I am trying to do a jQuery code so it does automatically click itself 50 times. All solutions I entered for this purpose does not show to be working...